# Allow direct access to some file/content in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, static

In my Asp.Net MVC application, I am using a customized template of twitter bootstrap.
I have placed this template folder named "b3-detail-admin" on root of my mvc application. 
Using Browser's address bar, when I am trying to access one file directly from this folder like so:

```
http://my-pc/MyWebAppMvc/b3-detail-admin/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

I am getting following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

What should I do to have direct access to all files/folders under "b3-detail-admin" folder?

Answer (score -1):

In mvc you can only get access to the routes defined in RouteConfig. 
You can add a ActionResult which returns the document like so:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf()
{
     string file = Server.MapPath("~/folder/file.pdf");
     return File(file, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
}
```

You then can make it dynamic to get all sorts of files:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string url, string mime)
{
     string file = Server.MapPath(url);
     string filename = url.Split(new char[]{'/'})[url.Split(new char[]{'/'}).Count()];
     return File(file, "mime", filename);
}
```

Comment: Actually I have this problem in my css file on following rule:
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

Can you tell me answer in this regard?

Comment: To address images and fonts in resources please use relative paths. Instead of the ../../.. just get it from the root directory: /Resources/Fonts/...

Comment: You are right but issue is actually occurring from one of bootstrap's css file and I have pasted in the problem part css in my last comment above. The paths are correct but browser console is still complaining the same error and this is only happening in the case of @font-face rule.

Comment: Could you post a picture or tell me the structuer of your application. I need to know how you formed your directory tree and then where  file with the error resides.